# How do I remove similar duplicates from text file using python?

Tags: python

I have written the following python code to remove the duplicates:

```
lines_seen = set()
outfile = open("out.txt", "w")
for line in open("file.txt", "r"):
    if line not in lines_seen: 
        outfile.write(line)
        lines_seen.add(line)
outfile.close()
```

The code above functions correctly and removes the exact same duplicates, but I want to be able to remove duplicates that have 3 or more exact word matches from a line. For instance:

```
The apple is red
The apple red
The banana is yellow
The apple is red
```

The output with the current code is:

```
The apple is red
The apple red
The banana is yellow
```

But I want to remove the phrase 'The apple red' as well because it has 3 matching words in the line. I hope this makes sense. How do I write this in python?

Comment: Are the lines always like that? Or do they contain punctuation etc?

Comment: I can think of ways to do this, but what happens is you have lines like: "The apple is red" and "The strawberry is red" - Technically they both have 3 words that match, should these be excluded too?

Comment: [difflib.get_close_matches](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches).

Comment: @AntonvBR For starters like me, the lines are always like that with no punctuation.

Comment: @LegendaryJLD Hmmm...Yeah, I guess these needs to be excluded too.

Comment: What about ["the apple is red", "the apple is", "the apple is yellow"]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple approach that may do what you want is to iterate over a list of the sets of words that have been seen in each line so far:

```
lines_seen = []
outfile = open("out.txt", "w")
for line in open("file.txt", "r"):
    words = set(line.split())
    for word_set in lines_seen:
        if len(words.intersection(word_set)) >= 3:
            break
    else:
        outfile.write(line)
        lines_seen.append(words)
outfile.close()
```

yields

```
The apple is red
The banana is yellow
```

Of course, this ignores some of the subtleties alluded to in the comments to your question. You may be better off with a specialized library such as [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at string distance functions:

1. Hamming distance
2. Levenshtein distance
3. Jaro–Winkler distance

There are also Python packages for [fuzzy string matching](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) - I believe this one implements method 2. These aren't going to do the word matching like you mentioned, but the string distance is perhaps a more robust method of achieving your goal.

Comment: I agree that the string distance is probably better, but all of these can be done at a word level, e.g. `from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz; print(fuzz.ratio("the apple is red".split(), "the apple is".split()))`.